# Angular 6: How to use FormGroup to create formControlName dynamically?

Tags: angular, forms, form-control, formgroups

I want formControlName Like this,

- field_0
- field_1
- field_2

myObj = {
  "field_0":"value_0",
  "field_1":"value_1",
   "field_2":"value_2",
  }
}

Comment: use `formArray` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of using a `formArray`:

```
    <div formArrayName="addresses"
         *ngFor="let address of addresses.controls; let i=index">

      <div [formGroupName]="i">
        <div class="form-group row mb-2">
          <label class="col-md-2 col-form-label"
                 attr.for="{{'street1Id' + i}}">Street Address 1</label>
          <div class="col-md-8">
            <input class="form-control"
                   id="{{'street1Id' + i}}"
                   type="text"
                   placeholder="Street address (required)"
                   formControlName="street1"
                   [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': (address.controls.street1.touched || 
                                              address.controls.street1.dirty) && 
                                              !address.controls.street1.valid }">
            <span class="invalid-feedback">
              <span *ngIf="address.controls.street1.errors?.required">
                Please enter your street address.
              </span>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

The form array is defined as `addresses` in this example.

The ngFor processes each address in the array, using `i` as the index. I can then use the `i` in the `id` field to define a unique id.

Each form array element is a form group.

The form group includes each element for an address. (I am only showing one of those elements here.)

You can find the complete example here: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-ReactiveForms/tree/master/Demo-Final

Comment: why you use a formArray? Am I missing something?

Comment: I only showed a small fraction of the example (and linked to the full code). My particular example allows the user to enter multiple address fields. So it is a form array of addresses where each address is a form group containing the set of address fields. And I assumed by the example that it was the *same* field multiple times. But maybe I misunderstood the example?

Comment: ::glups::, Perhaps I was who misunderstood the example -I only see an object, not an array of object, but the "}}" at the end of the object is not good for interpret the question

Comment: Good point regarding the `myObj`. Now the OP has both options so they can do with them what makes sense for their app. :-)

Answer (score 2):

if you have some like

```
fields=["field_0","field_1","field_2"]
```

You first must create a FormGroup

```
  createForm(fields: string[]) {
    let group: any = {};
    fields.forEach(x => {
      group[x] = new FormControl();
    })
    return new FormGroup(group);
  }
```

And, when you want show it

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <div *ngFor="let field of fields">
    <input [formControlName]="field">
  </div>
</form>
{{form?.value|json}}
```

Well, we can replace fields by an array of objects with label","field","value" to create the form

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m9nzn6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)