# Storing Angular reactive form validation rules in a database

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to start loading my forms re-actively from a database, with all the data for the controls stored in the database (MySQL).

I have an interface for the controls that looks like this:

```
export class IFormControl {
    type: string;
    label: string;
    name: string;
    value?: string;
    disabled?: boolean;
    placeholder?: string;
    validation?: [];
    options?: [];
}
```

And and example of what this should look like in my component after getting the info from the db:

```
    {
        type: 'input',
        label: 'Full name',
        name: 'name',
        placeholder: 'Enter your name',
        validation: [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4)],
        disabled: false
    }
```

Everything is fine except I am not sure what would be the best way to store my validation rules?

At the moment I am thinking of just taking the whole line, tuning it into a string, and storing it as such in a db 'text' field. Then when I retrieve it back, I would get the string `'Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4)'`, and just push the string into an array `['Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4)']`, and then with regex strip off all the quotation marks `[Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4)]`

Would this be the best way, or is there a better way to store and fetch the validators?

Comment: Personally I store in two variables validation (can be an integer) and args (string with the arguments). In the service, a map (or a foreach) and switch-case return the data with the array of validators

Comment: Do you maybe have an example of what you mean please? I just can't comprehend from the wording you use, and I have also tried up to now different other things that do not seem to work.

Comment: Its only an aprox of the problem, but I hope the answer help you to understand me. Well, I talk about a json, this json can be from a file, from a variable or from a dbs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's only an idea (and I haven't time to code).

Imagine you has a json like

```
[
{
   type: 'input',
   label: 'Full name',
   name: 'name',
   placeholder: 'Enter your name',
   validation: '1,2',
   args:'null,3'
}
{
   type: 'input',
   label: 'Full name',
   name: 'name2',
   placeholder: 'Enter your name2',
   validation: '1,2',
   args:'null,3'
}
]
```

you can has a service:

```
getFormModel()
{
  return httpClient.get("...").pipe(
    map(result=>{
      result.map(res=>{
         let validators=res.validation.split(,)
         let args=res.validation.split(,)
         let validator:any[]=[]
         for (let i=0;i<validators.length;i++)
         {
               switch (validators[i])
               {
                 case 1:
                    validator.push(Validators.required);
                    break;
                 case 2:
                    validator.push(Validators.MinLength(+args[i]);
                    break;
         }
         return 
         {
           type: res.type,
           label: res.label,
           name: res.name,
           placeholder: res.placeholder,
           validators:validator;
         }

      })
   })
)
}
```

when you subscribe you can create a FormGroup and store in model the model of the FormGroup like

```
myservice.getFormModel().subscribe(result=>
     let controls:any={}
     result.forEach(res=>{
        controls[res.name]=new FormControl('', res.validators)
     }
     this.myForm=FormGroup(controls)
     this.model=result;
)
```

And display like

```
<form formGroupName="myForm">
  <div *ngFor="let control in model">
      <input [formControlName]="control.name" 
             [placeholder]="control.placeholder"/>
  </div>
</form>
```

NOTE: One time you has the "model" you can show the controls like [the response of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53718663/angular-6-how-to-use-formgroup-to-create-formcontrolname-dynamically/53719621#53719621) (the stackblitz is more complex)

Comment: Ah ok thanks, I think I have the gist of it now. Was starting to think it might be something like this. Thanks for the answer.